# Why Vite proxying does not work with Post?

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy, vite

I'm creating an API to handle an image uploader for practice purposes. I'm using Express as backend and React+Vite for frontend. I'm running my server in port 3000, so I configure my Vite proxy server accordingly:

```
export default defineConfig({   
    server: {
         proxy: {       
            '/upload': 'http://localhost:3000',    
         }   
    },   
    plugins: [react()], 
})
```

As you can see, my endpoint is `/upload` and when I making GET request works perfectly but for POST request I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:5173/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

I checked the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html), I cannot see any ways to handle this issue.

Comment: The port in your POST info is `:5173` but you show the proxy to be `:3000` ?

Comment: Im running frontend in port 5173, this is why you see this error, but my API is running in port 3000.

Comment: Are there any errors on your server console?  If not errors, are there any logs to your server console?  Is SOMETHING actually trying to connect to :3000 ?